# Viewport height not calculated properly when iOS device is rotated to landscape

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, viewport

When in portrait mode viewport height is proper, but when I rotate the device to landscape the height is improper as if it takes portrait height (not sure though). I am using jquery mobile for web app. My viewport tag is :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale="1", maximum-scale="1", user-scalable="no" />
```

I don't give height and width still it works for portrait mode but not for landscape when rotated from portrait to landscape. Landscape only works when document is loaded in landscape mode but not when rotated.

Any suggestions pls help.

Markup:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>     
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />     <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />       
    </head>
    <frameset id="mainContainer" >
        <frame name="frame1" id="frame1" src="framesource1.php"/>
        <frame name="frame2" id="frame2" src="framesource2.php"/>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you getting the height?

Comment: i am not, but works this way properly in portrait mode.

Comment: Show us your markup.

Comment: ezanker I am still not able to solve this problem, pls suggest me something

Comment: Are you even using jQuery Mobile? Your issue might be with framesets. If you are coding a mobile web site, you might want to re-design and avoid using frames if possible...

Comment: jquery mobile is loaded inside these frames. if i want to redesign what to use instead of framesets ?

Comment: Hard to say knowing nothing about your web site, but look into panels, popups, and pages in the jQM demos.